# Hierarchy display Sybase table data

Tags: sql, sybase

```
EID     PID     Name

1       NULL    A
2       1       B
3       2       C
4       3       D
5       1       E
6       1       F
7       1       G
8       6       H
```

The above info shows actual data of a table, I want to display the data in that table as below .

i.e. Hierarchy display of data using EID and PID .

Here PID means ParentID, and EID is EntityID, Using ParentID we need to get the Hierarchy as below.

```
Level1  Level2 Level3  Level4

 A      NULL    NULL    NULL
 A       B      NULL    NULL
 A       B       C      NULL
 A       B       C       D
 A       E      NULL    NULL
 A       F      NULL    NULL
 A       F       H      NULL
 A       G      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Why so `mysql`, `sql-server`and `sybase` tag?

Comment: just self left join the table using Id = Pid columns, to get the level... i don't know is sysbase get somekind of recursive query like CTE in ms-sql

Comment: it won't work @jean .

Comment: is it fixed to max 4 levels?

Comment: as of now it is fixed to level4 only.

Comment: It works on SQL ill show a example, se my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: it's a example made in (**MS-SQL**)

@Gordon Linoff answer almost did it, just forgot the base case (**where Pid is null**)

just follow this pattern of left joins + unions to cover the base cases for a fixed amount of levels, for a dynamic number os levels you ill need to use recursion

```
declare @Tree as
table (
    Eid int not null
   ,Pid int null
   ,Name char(1) not null
)

insert into @Tree
values
 (1, NULL, 'A')
,(2,    1, 'B')
,(3,    2, 'C')
,(4,    3, 'D')
,(5,    1, 'E')
,(6,    1, 'F')
,(7,    1, 'G')
,(8,    6, 'H')

(
select t1.Name as [Level 1], null as [Level 2], null as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t1
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], null as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t1
left join @Tree t2 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], t3.Name as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t1
left join @Tree t2 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
left join @Tree t3 on t3.Pid = t2.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], t3.Name as [Level 3], t4.Name as [Level 4]
from @Tree t1
left join @Tree t2 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
left join @Tree t3 on t3.Pid = t2.Eid
left join @Tree t4 on t4.Pid = t3.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
) order by [Level 1], [Level 2], [Level 3], [Level 4]
```

**Edit:** and the same query using right join instead of left joins

```
declare @Tree as
table (
    Eid int not null
   ,Pid int null
   ,Name char(1) not null
)

insert into @Tree
values
 (1, NULL, 'A')
,(2,    1, 'B')
,(3,    2, 'C')
,(4,    3, 'D')
,(5,    1, 'E')
,(6,    1, 'F')
,(7,    1, 'G')
,(8,    6, 'H')

(
select t1.Name as [Level 1], null as [Level 2], null as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t1
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], null as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t2
right join @Tree t1 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], t3.Name as [Level 3], null as [Level 4]
from @Tree t3
right join @Tree t2 on t3.Pid = t2.Eid
right join @Tree t1 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
union
select t1.Name as [Level 1], t2.Name as [Level 2], t3.Name as [Level 3], t4.Name as [Level 4]
from @Tree t4
right join @Tree t3 on t4.Pid = t3.Eid
right join @Tree t2 on t3.Pid = t2.Eid
right join @Tree t1 on t2.Pid = t1.Eid
where t1.Pid is null
) order by [Level 1], [Level 2], [Level 3], [Level 4]
```

Comment: it's not working in mySQL, and any way it is not recommended to use as it takes much time to retrieve data.

Comment: saddly SQLFiddle is not working, cannot even run it and my mySql skills are rusty at best. It's really not a fast solution, the same table ill be scanned 10 times plus all that outer joins and unions. I guess learning how to use recursion on mySql can be a best option

Comment: i got solution for this but all null values in every row are at left side.
is there any way to move NULL values to right side.

Comment: sure (if I inderstant you), just change the joins order and use right join but it ill not improve the performance

Answer (score 1):

Because you know the number of levels, you can do this using `left join`:

```
select l1.name as level1, l2.name as level2,
       l3.name as level3, l4.name as level4
from data l1 left join
     data l2
     on l2.pid = l1.id left join
     data l3
     on l3.pid = l2.id left join
     data l4
     on l4.pid = l3.id;
```

Comment: it will displays like<br/>
 level1 | level2 | level3 | level4
--------+--------+--------+--------
 A      | B      | C      | D
 A      | E      | NULL   | NULL
 A      | F      | H      | NULL
 A      | G      | NULL   | NULL
 B      | C      | D      | NULL
 C      | D      | NULL   | NULL
 D      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
 E      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
 F      | H      | NULL   | NULL
 G      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
 H      | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
--------+--------+--------+--------
but i need only A in Level1, Level2 contains B,E,F and G and so on.

Comment: your code shows that Level1 contains A to H with A repeating 4 times.
And Level 2 contains "B,E,F,G" and "C,D,H" (which are not supposed to be in level 2).