# How to return hierarchical data?

Tags: sql

From employee table below, I need to retrieve an employee and the manager. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

tblEmployee:

```
empId    empName   manID
  1         A
  2         B        1
  3         C        2
```

Output:

```
Name  Manager
 A       -
 B       A
 C       B
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855387/hierarchy-display-sybase-table-data/28878075#28878075

Comment: You will have to post what you tried to get some help I have a feeling. If I were you though I would look into self joins.

Answer (score 1):

A pair of rudimentary approaches would be

```
SELECT 
 'Name' = empName 
 , 'Manager' = (SELECT empName FROM tblEmployee WHERE empID = e.manID)
FROM tblEmployee e
```

or

```
SELECT
  'Name' = e.empName
  , 'Manager' = ISNULL(m.empName, 'none')
 FROM tblEmployee e
   LEFT JOIN tblEmployee m
      ON e.manID = m.empID
```

There is probably a better approach depending on the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You simple need to join the table with itself:

For mysql it would be :

```
SELECT
  t1.empName AS 'Name',
  IFNULL(t2.empName, '-') AS 'Manager'
FROM 
  myTable t1
LEFT JOIN
  myTable t2
ON
  t1.manID = t2.empId
```

`t1` now would be the base-user, while `t2` would contain the manager, if present. If there is no manager, `t2.empName` will be `null` and then be replaced with a `-` by the `ifnull` function.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `Right` and `self` joins

```
select t2.empName, t1.empName as Manager from tblEmployee t1 
right Join tblEmployee t2 on t1.empID = t2.manID
order by empName
```